# android background service stops after some time

Tags: android, service, background

I have created a background service which is hitting my server on a regular interval but unfortunately, the background service stops after some time.

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //TODO do something useful

        new DownloadFilesTask().execute("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  return START_STICKY;
}


private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(siteurl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            return stringBuilder.toString();

        }
        finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
       return null;
    }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

   Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntent);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);

}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntent);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);


}

}
```

Comment: Use Job schedular to do you regular task or foreground service

Comment: i dont want foreground service , i want background service which send me information to server on regular intervals but my app service stops after 1-2 hours. please give me solution so that my service didn't stop by android OS

Answer (score 0):

With the latest release of Android API level 26, there is limit put on background services. Please refer [Background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services)

Comment: make it foreground, the only trade off is you will have notification

Answer (score 0):

onStartCommand will revoke automatically only if startService is called once from anywhere of your code. So declaring service only in Manifest would not enough.

**So, run service by calling**

```
startService(new Intent(context, serviceName.class));
```

Following above codes onStartCommand method will be revoked periodically if service is not stopped.

For your information, removing app from recent closes service. And

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

}
```

method is being called.

If you start service manually it will start again automatically even is being closed.

Comment: I have use this method but still not working for me. service still stop after a period of time